# How can I store filename in php variable in incremented way from for Loop

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for if my title is wrong.

Let me explain in detail here.

I want to store each filename in number-wise in `php` variable like

```
$image0 = filename.jpg
$image1 = filename.jpg
$image2 = filename.jpg
$image3 = filename.jpg
```

so on..

this filename.jpg is generate from for loop below is my code, current OP and expected OP.

```
$t = glob("/var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$productnumber."*", GLOB_BRACE);

            print_r($t);

            for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            //$t =asort($t);
            $proinfo = $t[$i];
            $path_parts = pathinfo($proinfo);
            echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
            echo $imagename = "/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$path_parts['basename']."\n\n";

            }
```

**Current OP**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228a.jpg
    [1] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228b.jpg
[2] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg
    [3] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228d.jpg

}

8573228a.jpg
/uploads/8573228/8573228a.jpg

8573228b.jpg
/uploads/8573228/8573228b.jpg

8573228c.jpg
/uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg

8573228d.jpg
/uploads/8573228/8573228d.jpg
```

**Expected OP**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228a.jpg
        [1] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228b.jpg
        [2] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg
        [3] => /var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/8573228/8573228d.jpg

    }

    8573228a.jpg
    /uploads/8573228/8573228a.jpg
$image0 =  "/uploads/8573228/8573228a.jpg";


    8573228b.jpg
    /uploads/8573228/8573228b.jpg
$image1="/uploads/8573228/8573228b.jpg";

    8573228c.jpg
    /uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg
$image2="/uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg";

    8573228d.jpg
    /uploads/8573228/8573228d.jpg
$image3="/uploads/8573228/8573228d.jpg";
```

So I can use this variable `$image0,$image1,$image2,$image3` in mysql query to insert data.

I tried to add this line inside for loop after `echo $imagearr`. But its not showing expected OP.

```
echo $image.$i = $path_parts[filename].$i."\n";
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

**EDIT**

Updated `$imagearr` variable name to `$imagename`. It might confuse to others between array `$t`**

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it by assigning dynamic variables ([Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as Darren commented correctly) like so:

```
$files = ['sunset.jpg', 'moon.jpg', 'jupiter.png', 'banana.gif'];
$count = 0;

foreach($files as $file) {
 ${'file' . $count} = $file;
 $count++;
} 

// output gives you 4 strings
var_dump($file0, $file1, $file2, $file3);
```

Comment: The correct terminology is [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but this is exactly how you do it. Nice Answer!

Comment: Great addition, I forgot about the exact name of this. +1

Comment: as my filename are stored in `$imagename` variable and not in array. Array stores full path and I have split that path using pathinfo(); and assigning only upto 2 parent directory and filename

Comment: @Ben I echo $file0 $file1 variables it shows complete path from `var to filename` I only want path from `$imagename` variable

Comment: Looking at your code `$t` is an array you can loop through. You can replace `${'file' . $count}` by `${'variable' . $count}` and you're set. Put a little work in it yourself as well. The approach in the answer explains how the desired result can be achieved. You only have to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: It shows parse fatal error after changing file to variable. I want variable like $file0. $file1 and it should store value of variable `$imagename` each time of for loop. Like simple `$file0 = $imagename;` now `i++` then again `$file1 = $imagename;` so on..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are *already getting multiple filenames and upload directory path*, and you just **need to assign to an auto-increment variable**.

**You just need to add this :**

```
echo $image.$i=$imagename; // it will give desired output '$image2="/uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg";'
```

**Your complete code :**

```
$t = glob("/var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$productnumber."*", GLOB_BRACE);

        print_r($t);

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        //$t =asort($t);
        $proinfo = $t[$i];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($proinfo);
        echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";

        echo $imagename= "/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$path_parts['basename']."\n\n";
        echo $image.$i = $imagename; // it will give desired output '$image2="/uploads/8573228/8573228c.jpg";'

        }
```

Comment: it only shows complete array value then `$path_parts` and `$imagearr`  then fatal error and only for first array value at location 0

Comment: @John, then I think you should use `$path_parts['basename'][$i]`. I guess it should work. But as your question says you are already getting output without using $i in name, so I didn't mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

try this example:

```
<?php
$array = array("variable1" => "value1","variable2" => "value2", "variable3" => "value3");
extract($array);
var_dump($variable1);
var_dump($variable2);
var_dump($variable3);
?>
```

output:

```
string(6) "value1" string(6) "value2" string(6) "value3"
```

In your case the following code should work:

```
$t = glob("/var/www/localhostmyproject.com/media/catalog/product/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$productnumber."*", GLOB_BRACE);

$images = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            $proinfo = $t[$i];
            $path_parts = pathinfo($proinfo);
            $imagename = "/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$path_parts['basename'];
            $images['image'.$i] = $imagename;

            }
            extract($images);

            var_dump($image0);
            var_dump($image1);
            var_dump($image2);
            var_dump($image3);
            var_dump($image4);
            var_dump($image5);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Put this in your code, you can get output:**

```
echo $imagearr = "/uploads/".$productnumber."/".$path_parts['basename']."\n\n";
echo $image.$i=$imagearr;
```

Comment: I tried using this way but it only shows first row then show parse error.